# Использования сокетов на сайте

Tags: php, сокет

Пользователь заходит на сайт. Вводит данные и т.д.
На компьютере у него стоит клиент. Нужно те данные, которые он ввел, отправить на этот клиент. Часть данных будет сохранена в базе, а часть отправится на компьютер.

Правильно ли с точки зрения программирания веб-служб отправлять нужные данные через сокет?
Я новичок в пхп, но мне кажется, что начальный запрос пользователя на сайт будет идти долго (пока оно сохранит в базе, пока создаст tcp подключения с компьютером и отправит на него данные).

Как правильнее написать?

Comment: @vviiviv - 

>никакого js

А кто, по вашему, будет обрабатывать данные сокета?

Comment: @vviiviv клиент на с++. Сайт на php, клиент отправляет данные на него, и уже сайт должен прислать ответ. Как будто клиент сервер, только с одной стороны у нас сайт.

Comment: @vviiviv - а что вам мешает дождаться ответа от сервера в виде JSON или XML и спокойной его разобрать?

Comment: @ua6xh нужно, чтобы сервер сам прислал ответ.

Comment: @ua6xh правильно ли будет, если прямо в том скрипте пхп, к которому идет запрос, инициализировать сокет? Или, возможно, можно как-то поставить в очередь, чтобы отправить потом?

Comment: @vviiviv - ну, вообще, сокет должен висеть отдельным демоном на сервере, если вы хотите сделать отложенную обработку, вам надо будет писать систему очередей при помощи какой-нибудь системы кеширования, поддерживающего стек (redis) или более подходящего инструмента типа брокера сообщений rabbitMQ.